# Reading XML for specific nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom

Let's say I have an XML like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <CreditCards>
        <Visa>
            <Name>visaname</Name>
            <Number>4265787654344445</Number>
            <ExpMonth>05</ExpMonth>
            <ExpYear>2017</ExpYear>
            <CVV>123</CVV>
        </Visa>
        <Master>
            <Name>mastername</Name>
            <Number>5678787654344445</Number>
            <ExpMonth>05</ExpMonth>
            <ExpYear>2015</ExpYear>
            <CVV>123</CVV>
        </Master>
    </CreditCards>
</Data>
```

Let's say I have a method like below

```
public void readData(String nodeName) {

//Code here

}
```

So when I use this method like

```
readData("Visa");
```

I should be printing all the child nodes and corresponding values. The output should look like this

```
Name = visaname
Number = 4265787654344445
ExpMonth = 05
ExpYear = 2017
CVV = 123
```

And

if I have an xml like below

```
<Data>
    <employee>
        <firstname>test1</firstname>
        <lastname>lasttest</lastname>
    </employee>
</data>
```

and If my method is like below

```
public void readData2(String nodeName) {

//Code here

}
```

when I use the method

```
readData2("firstname");
```

it should print the following

```
test1
```

Is it really possible? I tried using JDOM2 API but couldn't get it working. What would be the ideal way to achieve both the results? Thanks!!

Code I'm trying

```
public void readXMLData(String filePath) {

    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    Map<String,String> parametersMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //Root Element
        System.out.println("Root element : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Visa");
        System.out.println("----------Information of Visa Card----------");

        Node node = nodeLst.item(0);

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            System.out.println("Child nodes : "+element.getChildNodes());

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used DOM parser and it's not giving me the exact value of the node. It always returns null.

Comment: Added the code.. but it's just a rough one.

Comment: the Node.toString() is generally the wrong thing to output.  you need to call something like getTextContent().